# Lista de puntos 3D a partir de 2D

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Quiero conocer la dirección de la cara (head pose) y saber sus movimientos de translación y rotación.

Lo primero que hago es detectar si hay cara en la imagen y obtener todos los puntos que la representan mediante la librería `dlib`. A continuación muestro un mapa de los puntos de la cara.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cada punto me da dos valores, los cuales son sus coordendas XY en una lista, por ejemplo para dos puntos aleatorios si los imprimo obtengo:

```
(201, 203) (213, 187)
```

Según la [documentación](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d53/tutorial_py_pose.html) de `OpenCV` debo emplear la función `cv2.solvePnP()` y a esta introducirle los siguientes parámetros:

- objectPoints: Puntos 3D a trabajar.
- imagePoints: Puntos 2D.
- cameraMatrix: Matriz cámara.
- distCoeffs:coeficientes de distorsión.

Para los dos últimos si no leo mal en esta otra [documentación](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html) (la previa a la primera mostrada) los obtengo de aplicar `cv2.calibrateCamera()` pero resulta que a estos hay que volver a defnirle `objectPoints` y `imagePoints`.

Ahora mis dudas,

1. `imagePoints` son los puntos 2D, ¿debo entonces aquí introducirle los puntos obtenidos de las diferentes coordenadas de la cara?
2. `objectPoints`. Sinceramente, ni idea que es lo que debo introducir aquí, puesto que son la representación de los valores 3D de mis valores 2D y no entiendo cómo obtenerlos.

**Mi código:**

```
import dlib
import numpy as np
import cv2

detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector() # DETECTAR CARA DE FRENTE
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor("shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat") # Puntos de la cara
imgpoints = []
objpoints = []

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while(True):
    # 1. Preparo la imagen
    _, frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # 2. Detecto cara y puntos dlib
    faces = detector(gray)
    if len(faces) > 0:  # mirar lo del not none
        for face in faces:
            # Dibujo rectangulo cara
            x1, y1 = face.left(), face.top()
            x2, y2 = face.right(), face.bottom()
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 2)
            # Obtengo puntos de estudio
            landmarks = predictor(gray, face)
            p17 = (landmarks.part(17).x, landmarks.part(17).y)
            p18 = (landmarks.part(18).x, landmarks.part(18).y)
            # Dibujo puntos
            cv2.circle(frame, p17, 1, (0, 0, 255), -1)
            cv2.circle(frame, p18, 1, (0, 0, 255), -1)
            imgpoints.append(p17)
            imgpoints.append(p18)
            print(imgpoints)

    # 3. Empiezo FACE POSE
    ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1], None, None)
    ret, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.solvePnP(objpoints, imgpoints, mtx, dist)

    # 99. Muestro resultados
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

    #
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27: # Esc
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

¡Salud y gracias!

Comment: Conseguiste solucionarlo? Yo me encuentro ahora en un problema similar.

Comment: Lograste solucionarlo? tengo un problema similar